# How to remove app subfloder from url in cakephp

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I want to hide app subfolder from url.
Ex: http://abc.in/demos/gapps/User/signup
here User is sub folder of app. I want to remove foldername from url.
and access like this http://abc.in/demos/gapps/signup

Please help us coding
Present htaccess in main and app dirextories code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is not working
Please help me how to change.

Comment: use routing . . . ..

Comment: what version of cakephp you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Router::connect(
    '/url_Customized/*',
    array('controller' => 'Original_Controller_To_point_Like_users', 'action' => 'Your_Action_like_signup')
);
```

Refer [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html)

Comment: i added like this  Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'display', 'index'));        Router::connect('/user/*', array('controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'index'));

Comment: and defalut page connect is not commented

Comment: add  this in bottom of routes for signup page `Router::connect(
    '/signup',
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'signup')
);`